# Regex extract arbitrary number of subpatterns

Tags: python, regex, repeat

I have sentences that have the structure "Name has digit1 word1, digit2 word2, ..., and digitN wordN" where the number of subpatterns "digit word" varies across sentences, and therefore is uncertain. There is an "and" before the last subpattern. e.g. "Alice has 1 apple, 2 bananas, ...., and 6 oranges."

How can I extract these digits and words using regex in python? I expect output below:

Name,

| Digit | Word |
| --- | --- |
| digit1 | word1 |
| digit2 | word2 |
| ... | ... |
| digitN | wordN |

I have tried the following:

```
s = 'Alice has 1 apple, 2 bananas, and 3 oranges.'
import re
matches = re.finditer(r'([Aa-z]+) has (\d) ([a-z]+)( and)*', s)
for match in matches:
  print(match.groups())
```

But this only gives me ('Alice', '1', 'apple', None), missing '2', 'bananas', '3', 'oranges'.

Comment: Hey I made the changes you suggested. Please take a look!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [PyPi regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/).

**[See Python code](https://tio.run/##NY7LbsIwEEX3@Yq7i908JGCHSiL@oOsCCxMPxBKxrbGjFsS/Bye0mtFZXOmeGX@PvbObaTKDdxzBdKXfLGCHfH8zHaFXASso729UYo2zsmlCCWU1NnCs7JVCnWeDil1Pc3FR1BdjtYnEgnPRfn3@ONar5rCvvlX1OBVy9op2m/YYime5oE1M2kTZzh07Dmfi5qgLmbJ/y7o5vBXyIy8RZHZxjOU6jMXfG9sM8GxsFEtQd8rHkSlo00Uh5TS9AA)**:

```py
import regex
s = 'Alice has 1 apple, 2 bananas, and 3 oranges.'
matches = regex.finditer(r'(?P<word1>[A-Za-z]+) has(?:(?:\s+|,\s+|,?\s+and\s+)?(?P<number>\d+)\s+(?P<word2>[a-z]+))*', s)
for match in matches:
  print(match.capturesdict())
```

**Results**: `{'word1': ['Alice'], 'number': ['1', '2', '3'], 'word2': ['apple', 'bananas', 'oranges']}`

Comment: Good to know this regex library! Is there a way to also get the starting and ending positions of each matched number and word?

Comment: @LPat [Easy](https://tio.run/##fY7BbsIwEETv@YpVLrGbEIlwQ5CIP@Bc6MHEhlgia2vXqC3i31PHtJdKrXY1hx3N2/GfYXC4miY7ekcByFzMR8awhWJ3tb2BQTEsQXl/NRU0cFIYhytQqGEFjhReDNdFNqrQD2YOJkR9tqhtMCSoEN1@8@5IL9vDbvGqFve3Us5c0a3jHrl8VEm6qBEbVXZzBm/jyVB71KWMtx9K0x6eCPlSVMAyOzuC9B0swneNdQbgyWIQ6VD3yocbGda2D0LKXy57hSzy1DH/y322yf8LN9Gdpi8).

Comment: This is excellent! However, are the non-capturing groups necessary? [This](https://tio.run/##lU69bsIwEN7zFKcssZsQibBVEMQbMAMdTHwQS@RsnY2Aqu@eOqZdKrVSddI33PfrHqG3tBhHMzjLARjPeM88rKDYXEyH0CsPc1DOXbCCBo6K4vkKFGlYgGVFZ/Q1/EdcZIMKXY9TS@qrT4a0CciCC7HeLm@W9bzdb2Y7NXt/K@WUK8TBlx9VgnXEGBlRTnK6Dkfk9qBLGV/fAU27f7rlS1GBl9nJMqRiMARfC14zAMeGgkiPulMuXBm9Nl0QUv5gvVPkRZ7m5b@xzzX5X@YmsuP4CQ) seems to also work unless I'm missing something?

Comment: @LPat Force of habit: unnecessary here, they can help in other cases.

Comment: adding another layer of complexity to this and I'm hoping you could help me: if I have the word "large/small" in front of the fruit names, i.e. 2 large apples, how do I exclude "large/small" and only extract "apples"?

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to match everything in a single regex, you'd want something like this:

```
([^\s]+) has (?:(?:,\s+)?(?:and\s+)?(\d+)\s+([^\s,]+)){1,}
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tZaqtN/)

However, I'm not sure that python can handle a repeating group. At least, I haven't found a way to pull the repeating group from the python object.

So here's how I'd recommend approaching the problem:

```
import re

s = 'Alice has 1 apple, 2 bananas, and 3 oranges.'

matches = re.match(r'^([^\s]+)', s)
print(f'Name: {matches.group(0)}')

matches = re.findall(r'(?:(?:,\s+)?(?:and\s+)?(\d+)\s+([^\s,]+))', s)

for match in matches:
    print(f'{match[0]} - {match[1]}')
```

**Sample Output**

```
Name: Alice
1 - apple
2 - bananas
3 - oranges.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

**Regex Explanations**

`^([^\s]+)` - Few different ways to right this, but it's just grabbing everything until the first space in the string.

```
(?:           - Non-capturing group
 (?:,\s+)?    - Optionally allow the string to have a `,` followed by spaces
 (?:and\s+)?  - Optionally allow the string to contain the word `and` followed by spaces
 (\d+)        - Must have a number
 \s+          - Spaces between number and description
 ([^\s,]+)    - Grab the next set of characters and stop when you find a space or comma. This should be the word (e.g. apple)
)
```

This second regex just ensure you can pull various forms of the `1 apple`. So it will basically match the following patterns:

- `1 apple`
- `, 1 apple`
- `, and 1 apple`
- `and 1 apple`

As a side note a parser is better suited for these problems in the long-run. You get much more variance in the sentence and it starts becoming pretty difficult to parse using a simple regex.

Comment: Great article! I learnt a lot from it - it's a shame that re doesn't allow extracting both the Name and the repeating groups. Also very impressed that you wrote this within an hour of me posting my question. Really appreciate it!